# How to generate Order invoice by capturing "sales_order_save_after" event | Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, invoice-pdf

This is events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_save_after">
<observer name="mymodule_sales_order_save_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Observer" />
</event>
</config>
```

Here is Observer class:

```
class Observer implements ObserverInterface { 

protected $connector; public function __construct() { 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $this->orderId = $order->getId();
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('Catched event successfully');

  }
}
```

It is working fine till here, getting all values about order in Log.

Here is controller's execute function for invoice pdf:

```
public function execute()
{  
    $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if ($orderId) {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        if ($order) {
            $pdf = $this->orderPdfFactory->create()->getPdf([$order]);
            $date = $this->date->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
            return $this->fileFactory->create(
                'order' . $date . '.pdf',
                $pdf->render(),
                DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                'application/pdf'
            );
        }
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('sales/*/view');
}
```

After using this my Observer class becomes as:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
 */
protected $fileFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory
 */
protected $resultRedirectFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $orderRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
 */
protected $date;

/**
 * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Pdf\OrderFactory
 */
protected $orderPdfFactory;

protected $connector;
//public $OrderId;
protected $orderId;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Pdf\OrderFactory $orderPdfFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
) { 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $context->getResultRedirectFactory();
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->orderPdfFactory = $orderPdfFactory;
        $this->date = $date;
    }
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Sales::sales_order');
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $this->orderId = $order->getId();
        if ($orderId) {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        if ($order) {
            $pdf = $this->orderPdfFactory->create()->getPdf([$order]);
            $date = $this->date->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
            return $this->fileFactory->create(
                'order' . $date . '.pdf',
                $pdf->render(),
                DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                'application/pdf'
            );
        }
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('sales/*/view');

   }
}
```

Which is not working.. Can you show me how to correct it? Thanks

Comment: You have build custom module for creating pdf as `Vendor\Module\Model\Pdf\OrderFactory` is custom module Model file. Where you have generate  Invoice?

Comment: Hi @Amit Bera, I am doing it by extending this module's pdf print feature and there is no such file but it is working fine..I don't get it how..https://marketplace.magento.com/fooman-printorderpdf-m2.html. Could you check it please, if you have time.

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following piece of code in your observer.

```
$payment = $observer->getDataByKey('payment');
$order = $payment->getOrder();
$order->getId()
$order->getIncrementId();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Prema, issue is not about Order Id. I am getting it already.. It is about right use of 'execute function for invoice pdf' in observer.